# How do i get access to 'gseal'ed values from gtk widget | modify GtkWidgets

Tags: c, gtk

GTK uses the `GSEAL` option to prevent someones access to the Widget-struct.
That's great, because of objective programming in *C* you should use get-functions like in other languages.

Because there are no get-function for each value of `GtkButton`, I have some problems modifying my own `GtkWidgets`.

I want access to these values in `struct _GtkButton`

```
struct _GtkButton
{
    ....
    guint GSEAL (activate_timeout);
    guint GSEAL (in_button) : 1;
    guint GSEAL (button_down) : 1;
    ....
}
```

I want to add an `on-click` event for `mybutton`, to cancel click events before they will be called, so I decided to reimplement:

```
static void gtk_real_button_pressed(GtkButton *button)
{
    if (button->activate_timeout)
        return;

    button->button_down = TRUE;
    gtk_button_update_state(button);
}

static void gtk_real_button_released(GtkButton *button)
{
    if (button->button_down)
    {
        button->button_down = FALSE;

        if (button->activate_timeout)
            return;

        if (button->in_button)
        {
            // do my own stuff here  and maybe don'tcall "gtk_button_clicked(...)"
            gtk_button_clicked(button);
        }    
        gtk_button_update_state(button);
    }
}
```

as I say at the top I now need access to `button->in_button` for example.
Anybody has an clue, that could help me ? :)

---

by the way:

```
guint GSEAL (button_down) : 1;
```

I can't figure out whats the use of `: 1` in this case. :O

Comment: just found a solution. i will post it in 6 hours, because i have les then 10 reputation :O xD

Comment: the ": 1" means that only one bit of the type is going to be used, and the compiler should try to pack the structure more tightly if at all possible.

Comment: thx for the info,
actually found this out myself by diging through the memory in the debuger :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have never been supposed to access those fields in the `GtkButton` instance structure: they are private, and only available for internal use (the reason why they are not truly private like in modern GTK code is because `GtkButton` existed long before we could add instance private data inside `GObject` - long story).

The `GtkButton::clicked` signal is marked at `RUN_FIRST`, which means that the default signal handler associated to the class is run before any callback attached using `g_signal_connect()`.

If you want to prevent the `GtkButton::clicked` signal from being emitted (which is not a great idea to begin with, anyway) you can use a signal emission hook, or you can subclass `GtkButton` and stop the signal emission from within the default handler.

Comment: i am using gtk 2


i already subclassed Gtk Button now and looked up the gtk source code to rewrite "real_button_press" and "real_button_release"

Comment: in order to explan myself: i am writting a panel, that should enter a edit mode if i am holding down a button for about 5 seconds.
In editing mode all my buttons shouldn't rais their click event.
instead of using a boolean i want an "on-click" event and return an 'abort signal' if i need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NEVER** access the member variables like this. **EVER**. These are private variables. That is why GSeal was introduced. Your code may break on updates to GTK+

Comment: i realy know this, but in order to write my own Widgets, i have to overwrite some functions from the parent. in this case the "GtkButton".

i have to use gtk 2.10 because of an arm controller and cross compiler i use.
So in my case, gtk will not be updated! and if so, my widgets also should be updated. 

i looked up the "gtkbutton.c" and only rewrite a bit, for my needs, instead of changing gtkbutton.c.

Comment: if you need to do this, then you're doing it wrong. Ebassi told you the correct way to go about doing what you want to do. (Gtk2.10 doesn't use GSeal anyway.)

Comment: this was my first idea, to implement my needs.
didn't found an other way :/ 
btw: just saw i am using gtk 2.10 on arm and 2.24 on my pc.
your right, 2.10 doesn't use GSEAL. i am looking forward to find another solution, like ebassi said.

Answer (score 0):

I now use this little function, using the gseal values was realy nothing i should do.

```
typedef struct _GuiOnClickHandler   GuiOnClickHandler;
struct _GuiOnClickHandler
{
    gboolean abortClick;

};

static void gui_recipe_button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GuiOnClickHandler handler;
    handler.abortClick = FALSE;

    g_signal_emit_by_name((gpointer)widget, "on-click", &handler);

    if (handler.abortClick)
        g_signal_stop_emission_by_name((gpointer)widget, "clicked");
}

...somewhere else on init, at first place

    g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked",
            G_CALLBACK (gui_recipe_button_clicked), NULL);
```